# How to start Mountebank in Docker?

Tags: docker, travis-ci, mountebank

How can I use Docker to start Mountebank as a server? I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/06/mule-esb-testing-part-33-system-end-to-end-testing-with-docker/) but I can't make it work.

This error appears:

```
warn: [mb:2525] dry running injection, use the isDryRun request field in your JavaScript to ignore...
error: [mb:2525] injection X=> SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
error: [mb:2525]     source: "(function(request, logger) { return JSON.parse(request.data).hasOwnProperty('state'); })(scope, logger);"
error: [mb:2525]     scope: {"requestFrom":"","data":"test","isDryRun":true}
```

The project is [open source](https://github.com/takenet/messaginghub-client-js) and [CI is Travis](https://travis-ci.org/takenet/messaginghub-client-js/builds/99244925#L173). I have [cross-posted this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mountebank-discuss/m-UrVZBR1sQ) to the Mountebank mailing list.

Comment: Be aware that @bbyars, the creator is aware of this and has an issue open regarding Docker and Mountebank following what shek has answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the base Docker image is using an old version of mountebank (v1.2.122).  I'm not super familiar with Docker, but I assume it's caching the image originally built by Conrad.  Your config file works fine with the latest version of mountebank; that just needs to be installed in the Docker container. - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mountebank-discuss/m-UrVZBR1sQ